# SignalR SendAsync not sending the message to all the clients

Tags: c#, .net, connection, signalr

I have the following code:

```cs
private readonly List<string> _connectionIds = new List<string>();
    
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    _connectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    _connectionIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
    await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```

It's the most basic way to manage the connection IDs of SignalR...

But then, I have this iteration:

```cs
foreach (string con in _connectionIds)
{
    await Clients.Client(con).SendAsync("message");
}
```

The problem is that not all the conected clients get the message, but the last connected one gets all the messages.

And if I run:

```cs
await Clients.All.SendAsync("message");
```

Then all the clients are getting the message, so they are all connected.

I've also tried with `ConcurrentDictionary`, `lock`, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and even recursivity over the `Hub.Clients` to make sure the connection IDs I'm calling are correct.

Any idea why? Thank you!

Update: I found out that it only happens with .NET 7, so it might be a bug in the library.

Comment: Hubs are transient, meaning you get a new instance of the hub class per method call. This means your list of connection IDs will always be a new list and not keep the state from previous calls. You either need to make it static (and make sure it's thread safe) or inject a service from DI that is a singleton.

Comment: The Hubs are injected as singleton already.

Comment: Don't add Hubs to DI, that will cause issues. Instead make a separate class that you inject into DI that has your app logic.

Comment: Brennan do you have an example of how to do this? I am encountering the same problem right now.